# Creating local self-signed Certificate for user 'tomcat'

Tags: ssl, tomcat, csr, keystore

When I installed Tomcat 8 on my Ubuntu 15.04 I used the following command to create the user "tomcat":

```
sudo adduser \
  --system \
  --shell /bin/bash \
  --gecos 'Tomcat Java Servlet and JSP engine' \
  --group \
  --disabled-password \
  --home /home/tomcat \
  tomcat
```

As a consequence, I don't have a password. Now I need to generate a CSR in order to install the SSL certificate on Tomcat 8. For that I am using [this tutorial](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Create_a_local_Certificate_Signing_Request_(CSR)).

While running command `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore <your_keystore_filename>` it requests a password for user 'tomcat'. I tried hitting ENTER but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I don't think that keytool command is asking you the password for tomcat user. Generating a self-signed certificate has nothing to do with the system user. Keytool command ask you to set the password for the certificate you are generating.

```
keytool  -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /applications/certs/test.key
Enter keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  example.com
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  test
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  test
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  delhi
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  delhi
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  IN
Is CN=example.com, OU=test, O=test, L=delhi, ST=delhi, C=IN correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <tomcat>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):  
Re-enter new password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `openssl` commandline. You will find a lot of howtos for creating self signed certificates.

Comment: With Tomcat `keytool` is the way to go.